# Playwright Locator not clickable?

Tags: javascript, playwright

I try to click a link on a page, but the locator to get this link does not seem to work, even though the debugging window (I use headed mode) highlights the link. What could be the reason?

The debugging window shows:

[image]

The highlight suggests that the link seems to be found. The code to find the link looks like this:

```
await page
  .locator("text=Lehrveranstaltungen")
  .first() /* it does not matter whether I use .first() or not */
  .waitFor();
```

Instead of `waitFor()` for I also tried `click()` and `boundingBox()`. All these methods lead to the same result. Playwright logs `locator.waitFor started` (see the last line of the following image), however the wait (or click when I use `click()`) does not succeed. Also, the Playwright Inspector shows the play button and step over button grayed out, once the code reaches the `waitFor()` (or `click()` if I use `click()` instead of `waitFor()`).

All the clicks before that did succeed (see the lines before the last one in the following image), so I am wondering why the last locator isn't working. Any ideas are highly appreciated ️

[image]

Comment: Can you try this locator? ‘(//*[@text()="Lehrveranstaltungen"])[1]‘. Try to find It out in dev tool from your browser and let see if It is valid

Comment: And can you try to click it by Javascript? `page.evaluate('document.getElementByXpath("‘(//*[@text()=\"Lehrveranstaltungen\"])[1]");')`

Comment: Thank you for having a look at it, Jaky! I just tried it with `.locator('(//*[@text()="Lehrveranstaltungen"])[1]')`, but this doesn't even highlight the text that I would like to click :( Did I misspell something?

Comment: With `page.evaluate('document.getElementByXpath("‘(//*[@text()="Lehrveranstaltungen"])[1]");');` I get the following error: `page.evaluate: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`. I'm not very familiar with XPath, so I don't know how to fix this error :(